# Three dots directory traversal with mv

Tags: linux, command-line

Where does the file go if you execute the following command:

```
mv <file> ...
```

Note that there is no directory with the name `...` in the current directory.

Comment: Create a dummy file and try it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There may be no directory with the name `...` in the current directory, but you're creating a file with that name. (Because it starts with a `.`, it's hidden).

You can see such hidden files if using the `-a` argument to `ls`:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..
$ touch file; mv file ...; ls -a
.  ..  ...
```

Comment: how come I can cd into `...` at any time (except inside `...` already)? [in GitBash, i'm assuming normal linux is the same]

Comment: `cd ...` is not supported on Linux unless a directory named `...` exists.

Comment: @ThorSummoner, ...however, `...` has special meaning on Windows, unrelated to bash; see http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/32.html

Comment: you can use `cd '...'` to get into `...` directory.

Comment: @tGilani, that'll work identically with or without quotes -- there's no shell expansion happening there for quotes to suppress.